# Paypal payment integration

Tags: php, paypal

I already have integrated paypal payments into my website but the code is pretty basic and am not confident about how secure it is, so i began searching for a more secure and a bit complex code for paypal integration and recently stumbled onto this one, the issue is i only understand bits of the code in the notify/listener.php i would like someone to really break it down and explain it all in simpler terms like for example i dont understand the get magic quotes part of the script

```
// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);
// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "ipn.log");
// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}
// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.
//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}
// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    
    include("DBController.php");
    $db = new DBController();
    
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    $isPaymentCompleted = false;
    if($payment_status == "Completed") {
        $isPaymentCompleted = true;
    }
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    $isUniqueTxnId = false; 
    $param_type="s";
    $param_value_array = array($txn_id);
    $result = $db->runQuery("SELECT * FROM payment WHERE txn_id = ?",$param_type,$param_value_array);
    if(empty($result)) {
        $isUniqueTxnId = true;
    }   
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    if($isPaymentCompleted) {
        $param_type = "sssdss";
        $param_value_array = array($item_number, $item_name, $payment_status, $payment_amount, $payment_currency, $txn_id);
        $payment_id = $db->insert("INSERT INTO payment(item_number, item_name, payment_status, payment_amount, payment_currency, txn_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", $param_type, $param_value_array);
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Vdddddddddddderified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    } 
    // process payment and mark item as paid.
    
    
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"i dont understand the get magic quotes part"* ... probably for the best, that rubbish has been defunct for years. This script looks **dangerously** out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use anything from that code, it's very old.

Here is a far better HTML/JS sample for basic payments: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Jist:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Add meta tags for mobile and IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title> PayPal Smart Payment Buttons Integration | Client Demo </title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD"></script>

    <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({

            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: '88.44'
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },

            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                });
            }


        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This jist is subject to decay over time from the writing of this post, always consult the developer paypal Client integration portal walkthrough for most updated examples.